# Why am I unable to see my content on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-development-server

I am working on a Amazon clone with React.js but when I run my code  
I don't see any content on the webpage 
here is my code

[image]

And here is the webpage

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. Open the console on your browser to checkout the error. `[CTRL + SHIFT + I]` in chrome.

Comment: "Uncaught Error: [Header] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>" This is what I got

Answer (score 0):

Open the **console** on your browser to checkout the error. **[CTRL + SHIFT + C]** in **Mozila**.

Comment: "Uncaught Error: [Header] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>"      This is what I got

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of react router are you using.

Instead of passing elements as children, use the element props as mentioned in [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route)

Example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<><Header /><Home /></>} />
```

> "Uncaught Error: [Header] is not a  component. All component
> children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>"

or try wrapping children with `React.Fragment` or `<></>`

```
 <Route path="/">
   <>
     <Header />
     <Home />
   </>
 </Route>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, I just have one more question I am very new to React.js so now I get this error "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."   Do you know what it means?

Comment: Please accept the answser if the solution works. For the keys error check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js) and [this](https://sentry.io/answers/unique-key-prop/) . You can also [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+each+child+unique+key&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN1005IN1005&oq=React+each+child&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l4j0i390l5.5709j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) the error for more results